# rust pass box reference without move

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Background:

I'm writing a RDBMS in rust

The db.catalog maintain a hashmap from table_id to table:

```rust
pub struct Catalog {
    table_id_table_map: HashMap<i32, Box<dyn Table>>,
}
```

And when I add a boxed table to the catalog, move occurred. Then I can't use table instance anymore:

```rust
// create table
let table = create_random_heap_table(....);
// add to catalog
db.get_catalog().add_table(Box::new(table), "heap table", "");
// access table instance
let table_id = table.get_id();
```

compile error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `table`
   --> src/lib.rs:113:32
    |
103 |                 let table = create_random_heap_table(
    |                     ----- move occurs because `table` has type `table::HeapTable`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
111 |                 db.get_catalog().add_table(Box::new(table), "heap table", "");
    |                                                     ----- value moved here
112 | 
113 |                 let table_id = table.get_id();
    |                                ^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Comment: `Box` takes full ownership of the value by *moving* `table`. You can implement `Copy` or `Clone` but then `table` and whats in the `Box` won't be the same object. You should either let the catalog *own* the table and just make references to it, or use shared ownership via `Rc`.

Answer (score 1):

Once your `Catalog` takes ownership of the table, you can access it via reference.

If the use case you are describing is common, maybe you can adapt your `add_table` method to return a reference to the table which has just been added.

`HashMap` provides the [`Entry`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html) API as an ergonomic way to do this - for instance your `add_table` might look something like this:

```
fn add_table(&mut self, table: Box<dyn Table>/*, ... other arguments */) -> &mut Box<dyn Table> {

    let id = // figure out id somehow

    // Insert table into catalog and return a reference to it        
    self.table_id_table_map.entry(id).or_insert(table)
}
```

In that simplified example I am not considering what happens if the map already has an entry with the given `id` - there are similar patterns you can use to check for that if you logic requires it.

Now you can use it like this:

```
// create table
let table = create_random_heap_table(....);
// add to catalog
let table = db.get_catalog().add_table(Box::new(table), "heap table", "");
// access table instance
let table_id = table.get_id();
```

Comment: I use Rc<dyn Table> as value  in finally